# get rid of column and transpose table

Tags: r, perl, bash

I have a table in a text file it is space delimited. As it is very large, I cant really use R. is there a simple way to get rid of the first column, then transpose the table and than add to indexcolums (just from 1 to nrow table) as columns 1 and 2?

The table in the moment looks like

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 1 1 1 2 3 0 0
```

Is there a quick way in R, perl or bash (awk)to do that?

Comment: `table<-t(table[,-1])` will do the first part but I don't get what you want to do after.

Comment: `As it is very large, I cant really use R` - I highly doubt that. How large is `very large`, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use Perl, you could try out the [`PDL`](http://p3rl.org/PDL) Module. Here a Basic example of your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDL;

my @array = (
  [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ],
  [ 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
  [ 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
  [ 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, ],
);

# unshift first element of each line
unshift @{$_} foreach @array;

my $m = PDL->pdl( @array );
print $m->transpose;
```

Output:

```
[
 [1 2 3 4]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 2]
 [0 0 0 3]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
]
```

Further informations: [here](http://pdl.perl.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only expressing your example in numerical values without variables, I assume you would rather use a matrix. Using base functions, you could perform the following (column removal courtesy of @Vincent:

```
table <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
 +                2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
 +                3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 +                4,1,1,1,2,3,0,0), 
 +                nrow = 4, ncol = 7, byrow=TRUE) #Recreates your example above

table <- table[,-1] #Removes the first column by index number (as indicated by @Vincent in your comment above)

table <- t(table) #Transposes your matrix

table 
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    0    1
[4,]    0    0    0    2
[5,]    0    0    0    3
[6,]    1    0    0    0
[7,]    0    0    0    0 #Output
```